# Problem in installing fasttext in M1 Mac - python 3.8

Tags: python, machine-learning, fasttext

**Tried the following command for installing fasttext**

```
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" fasttext
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - fasttext

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

**Tried this approach**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ pip install .
```

**and got this error**

Building wheels for collected packages: fasttext
Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [67 lines of output]

.....

raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: libc++ is needed! Failed to compile with -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 and -stdlib=libc++.
[end of output]

Comment: Why does your conda install attempt specify `-c "conda-forge/label/cf202003"`? IIUC, that will limit their index to packages that were available at the moment Conda-Forge ended Python 2.7 support a few years ago. If you're using Python 3.8, I'm not sure why you'd want that limit, so what happens when you try a plain `conda install fasttext`?

Comment: Tried this `conda install fasttext`

Getting the following error

`Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for channel fasttext <https://conda.anaconda.org/fasttext>

The channel is not accessible or is invalid.

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.`

Comment: It's very hard to interpret long error messages in comments; you should generally update your question with such new, long information that would benefit from whitespace-sensitive quoting. That error suggests you may still be in an environment looking for things in nonstandard channels, and/or in a channel named `fasttext` - so may be a lingering aftereffect of other failed attempts. Try starting fresh - either in new conda environment or all-new conda installation after removing the old. And, follow the error's implied suggestion to "view your configuration's current state" for ideas.